# Autofill a field of a polygon from a field within a point

Tags: qgis, polygon, point-in-polygon

Is there a way I can autofill a polygon field from a point field that’s located inside the polygon?

I have a lot of polygon attributes that I need to fill and it would take a while. The points are already existing within the polygon. I was hoping to just click the polygon and auto fill a specific attribute from the name of the point.

I am new to QGIS so I don't really understand the coding side.

Comment: Is there only one point per polygon?

Comment: Try using an expression with [overlay_intersects](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects), look at the examples

Comment: Yes, there is only one point per polygon I am trying to retrieve data from. I’m trying to fill a field in the polygon with the name of that point